Largest normal distribution under a curve
I was wondering if I could have some insights on the following problem.
Suppose I have a probability distribution $F$, I want an algorithm that finds the largest normal distribution under $F$.
Say we have $n$ obersvations of $X$, then we want the smallest subset $I \subseteq [n]$ such that $X_{[n]} \backslash X_I$ is normally distributed.
The context is a game where players vote a ground truth that is unknown. Suppose p > 1/2 players vote N(1,sigma) (say ground truth is 1 but mechanism doesn't know it) and the rest of players skew this to the right by voting above 1. Is there a way to detect the normal distribution of the honest voters ? Here the mechanism doesn't know p and doesn't know that the ground truth is 1.

You could try making a QQ plot of your data and throwing out samples that deviate the most from a linear fit

Interesting, that could work for a skewed normal distribution. Do you think it would still work for distributions that would be say a combination of X and Y where X is N(1, sigma) and Y is N(2,gamma) ? So a scenario where it isn't very clear what we are looking at ? So a distribution where we want to find the strongest "sub" distribution that is normal, and some observations delibereately try to skew and cheat the observations. In this case Y would represent 30% of observations and X is 70%, could the QQ plot detect that X is strongest ?
